# How to initialize leaflet routing line

Tags: routes, line, leaflet, mapbox

Does anybody knows how to create new line object of `L.Routing.line()`.

I want to draw routing line between two points.  I am able to achieve it through `L.Routing.control` however it is adding direction control which I do not required.

Please provide example.

Comment: Do you have any code you can provide to show what isn't working that you have attempted? Is this a plugin you are using?

Answer (score 3):

```
var router = L.Routing.osrm(),waypoints = [],line;
waypoints.push({latLng: L.latLng(52.19226,0.15216)});
waypoints.push({latLng: L.latLng(52.15247,0.14019)});

router.route (waypoints,function(err, routes) {
        if (line) {
            map.removeLayer(line);
        }

        if (err) {
            alert(err);
        } else { 
            line = L.Routing.line(routes[0]).addTo(demo_layer);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I should mention that this just draws a nice line around Cambridge UK :)

Comment: As of October 2019, the router must be defined as:
`var router = L.Routing.osrmv1()`